# How can i implement Role Based Authorization in ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I want to understand how we can use role based authorization in ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor Pages. Like previously on controller we could authorize but since there are not more controllers how do we achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing changes.

Just put [Authorize(Roles = "RoleName")] above the razor class name.

...

```
  [Authorize]
  public class IndexModel : PageModel
  {
    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
  }
```